# Can't open CSS files in Visual Web Developer Express

Tags: visual-studio, vwdexpress

I've checked for other with the same problem and found only three suggestions (reinstall, remove an update and restore files associations).

I haven't installed any updates, i've tried to reinstall the whole shabang (successfully) and i tested to restore the file ass'es. All to no avail.

When i click on the CSS-files i still get the message:

*"The operation could not be completed. Undefined error.*

That goes for all the projects and only CSS files (as far as i can see). The sites work properly as before. It's just the IDE that can't open the darned files! Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was really strange. The solution proved to be to install Web Standards from Scott Hanselman, remove it and THEN install it again. Truly strange indeed.